# image in IE doesn't display

Tags: javascript, html, image, internet-explorer, firefox

Could you please help me that this code doesn't work in IE? But this one works with firefox
I think I'm missing something

Thanks

```
<html>
<head>
<title>tintin</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<style type="text/css"> 
#tintin{
position: relative;
top: 100px;
left: 100px;
font-size:18pt;
color:white;
font-style:bold;
font:Calibri;
filter:alpha(opacity=0);
opacity:0;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

var txt=['text 1','text 2', 'text 3', 'text 4', 'text 5', 'text 6', 'text 7', 'text 8', 'text 9', 'text 10'], init=0,i=0,k=0,speed=50,el;
var loopCount=6;
var j=0;
function fade(){
init==0?i++:i--;
el.filters?el.style.filter='alpha(opacity='+i+')':el.style.opacity=i/100;
el.firstChild.nodeValue=txt[k];
if(i==100)init=1;
if(i==0) {init=0;k++;j++;} 
if(k==txt.length)k=0;
if (j<loopCount) setTimeout('fade()',speed);
}
window.onload=function(){
el=document.getElementById('tintin');
fade();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="tintin">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div class="image">
  <img alt="" src="test.jpg" />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? What happens? What errors do you get?

Comment: first mention what you are willing to do with your code ?

Comment: @Viswanathan Iyer: I would like to have the image being shown in IE 8. In IE 9 it works and in Firefox. Now I found the answer. I had a 2 MB jpg and as far as I know the IE 8 can't handle such sizes. So I compressed the picture and now it displays in both browsers. Sorry for this repeatedly question. I actually posted here: if you can see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5880037/text-in-a-clockwise-direction-using-javascript I would like to have the text appear from left to right but like in a circular motion

Comment: Then it's probably a CMYK image. Size shouldn't be a problem

Comment: @Pekka: How can I change the text color just to simply white?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's not the size of image. I had a similar issue. In my case was the extension of the image that was different from the real encoding. I had saved a jpg/png image with gif extension. All browser recognized the image in the real format (not the in the extension), but IE not.